# How to properly delete those pointers?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, smart-pointers

This is my allocation:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numCols; i++)
{
    columnNameLen = new SQLSMALLINT *[numCols];
    columnDataType = new SQLSMALLINT *[numCols];
    columnDataSize = new SQLULEN *[numCols];
    columnDataDigits = new SQLSMALLINT *[numCols];
    columnDataNullable = new SQLSMALLINT *[numCols];
    columnData = new SQLWCHAR *[numCols];
    columnDataLen = new SQLLEN *[numCols];
    columnName = new SQLWCHAR *[numCols];
}

for (int i = 0; i < numCols; i++)
{
    columnNameLen[i] = new SQLSMALLINT;
    columnDataType[i] = new SQLSMALLINT;
    columnDataSize[i] = new SQLULEN;
    columnDataDigits[i] = new SQLSMALLINT;
    columnDataNullable[i] = new SQLSMALLINT;
    columnDataLen[i] = new SQLLEN;
    columnName[i] = new SQLWCHAR[256];
}
```

And this is my deletion :

```
for (int i = 0; i < numCols; i++)
{
    delete columnNameLen[i];
    columnNameLen[i] = NULL;
    delete columnDataType[i];
    columnDataType[i] = NULL;
    delete columnDataSize[i];
    columnDataSize[i] = NULL;
    delete columnDataDigits[i];
    columnDataDigits[i] = NULL;
    delete columnDataNullable[i];
    columnDataNullable[i] = NULL;
    delete columnData[i];
    columnData[i] = NULL;
    delete columnDataLen[i];
    columnDataLen[i] = NULL;
    delete[] columnName[i];
    columnName[i] = NULL;
}

for (int i = 0; i < numCols; i++)
{
    delete[] columnNameLen;
    columnNameLen = NULL;
    delete[] columnDataType;
    columnDataType = NULL;
    delete[] columnDataSize;
    columnDataSize = NULL;
    delete[] columnDataDigits;
    columnDataDigits = NULL;
    delete[] columnDataNullable;
    columnDataNullable = NULL;
    delete[] columnData;
    columnData = NULL;
    delete[] columnDataLen;
    columnDataLen = NULL;
    delete[] columnName;
    columnName = NULL;
}
```

Is the code above OK? I probably should just use smart pointers, but I don't know how the code will look like with them? So if you throw in a smart-pointer code it would be greatly appreciated. Those pointers are used locally in the thread function and not shared with anything.

I fear that the second loop needs just `delete` and not `delete[]`.

TIA!

Comment: get into using c++ idiomatic constructs, you will never regret it. std::vector, std::shared_ptr and std::string (not clear if you already use that)

Comment: are those things meant to be 2 dimensional? why not just `new SQLSMALLINT [numCols]`

Comment: @pm100, yes, it is meant to be 2-dimensional.

Comment: @pm100, how it will look like with shared_ptr?

Comment: you sure about 2D, I think you just have a single array of columnNameLen , columnDataType,... You first code allocated many arrays but only uses one of them (for each of columnNameLen,...)

Answer (score 7):

You shouldn't use pointers *at all* here.

```
using SQLSTRING = std::basic_string<SQLWCHAR>;

struct Column
{
    SQLSTRING Name;
    SQLSTRING Data;
    SQLSMALLINT DataType;
    SQLULEN DataSize;
    SQLSMALLINT DataDigits;
    SQLSMALLINT DataNullable;
}

std::vector<Column> columns(numCols);
```

Comment: this is why I asked about really needing 2D, but OP says 'yes they are supposed to be 2D'.

Comment: @Caleth, the code is being used to retireve the db result information prior to fetch actual data. I think using std::vector is just an overkill for sch simple task. Especially, since in order to retrieve the data from the cursor the code will be simply ugly: SQLGetData( m_hstmt, 1, columns.DataType.at( 0 ),.....); But that's my opinion.

Comment: @Igor exactly wrong std:vector is simply and correctly doing what you were unsuccessfully trying to to

Comment: @Igor `std::vector` is the *default* container. Forget that C-style arrays exist, forget that `new` exists

Comment: @Igor and the usage is not very different: the `[]` comes between the `columns` and the `DataType` and you have references not pointers. e.g. `SQLGetData( m_hstmt, 1, columnDataType[0],.....)` -> `SQLGetData( m_hstmt, 1, &columns[0].DataType,.....)`

Answer (score 5):

Don't use `new` and `delete` in user code. Use `std::vector<>`.

Regarding `new` and `delete`:

All objects allocated with `new` have to be deallocated by `delete`,
all objects allocated with `new[]` have to be deallocated by `delete[]`.

Also make sure you follow the [Rule of 3/5](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). (The [Rule of 0](https://isocpp.org/blog/2015/01/the-rule-of-zero-glennan-carnie) ... which you should aim for ... is out of question if you don't use smart pointers or other objects that follow RAII/RDID to wrap raw owning pointers).

Answer (score 2):

Your code is leaking memory, since in your first loop, you overwrite again and again the same pointers (loosing the previous value and this never freeing it).

For the deallocation, the second loop is unnecessary.  This will avoid taht you delete the first time the pointer and the next iterations try to delete nullptr.

By the way:

- use nullptr instead of NULL
- you may also use shared_ptr or unique_ptr depending instead of raw pointer.
- use vectors instead of arrays, if it's feasible.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot to give up on pointers (sometimes there's no other way) and don't want any of the suggested alternatives either, consider using a `SCOPE_EXIT` lookalike, like `Boost.ScopeExit`. You can then do something like:

```
SCOPE_EXIT(p, delete p);
```